# Need to update PSQL row of a composite type in golang with jack/pgx

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I am trying to insert/update data in PostgreSQL using jackc/pgx into a table that has column of composite type. This is the table type written as a golan struct:

```golang
// Added this struct as a Types in PSQL
type DayPriceModel struct {
    Date                time.Time `json:"date"`
    High                float32   `json:"high"`
    Low                 float32   `json:"low"`
    Open                float32   `json:"open"`
    Close               float32   `json:"close"`
}
```

// The 2 columns in my table

```
type SecuritiesPriceHistoryModel struct {
    Symbol  string          `json:"symbol"`
    History []DayPriceModel `json:"history"`
}
```

The column `history` is an array of composite type which I have defined as DayPriceModel in PSQL. I want to append a new element to `history` in golang using `jack/pgx`

I have so far written the given code:

```golang
// The code for newType was generated by ChatGPT so it might or might not be correct. Feel free to overwrite this part.
newType, _ := pgtype.NewCompositeType("day_price_model", []pgtype.CompositeTypeField{
            {Name: "date", OID: pgtype.DateOID},
            {Name: "high", OID: pgtype.Float4OID},
            {Name: "low", OID: pgtype.Float4OID},
            {Name: "open", OID: pgtype.Float4OID},
            {Name: "close", OID: pgtype.Float4OID},
        }, (*pgtype.ConnInfo)(pool.Config().ConnConfig.TLSConfig.ClientCAs))

_, err = pool.Exec(context.Background(), `UPDATE equity.securities_price_history
SET history = $1::equity.day_price[] || history WHERE symbol = $2`,
composite_value_here, "something") // unable to form the composite_value_here variable
```

Using jack/pgx, how do I create a new composite value from a composite type to write in the PSQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requirements**

- composite type is defined using `psql`
- updating/inserting into a column of type array of composite type
- using `github.com/jackc/pgx/v5`

The easiest way is to use `pgx.LoadType()/pgx.RegisterType()` and use the composite type already defined in the db.

Since we have an array of composite type we need to do it for both, the composite type itself and the array type (you can check with `select 'day_price_model'::regtype::oid;` respectively `select 'day_price_model[]'::regtype::oid;` that the oids are different).

For registration we can take `RegisterDataTypes` from the [v5/pgtype documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype).

Assuming the type was created with `psql` as follows:

```
create type day_price_model as (
    date date,
    high float,
    low  float,               
    open float,
    close float
);
```

the `RegisterDataTypes` could look sth like:

```
func RegisterDataTypes(ctx context.Context, conn *pgx.Conn) error {
    dataTypeNames := []string{
        "day_price_model",
        "day_price_model[]",
    }

    for _, typeName := range dataTypeNames {
        dataType, err := conn.LoadType(ctx, typeName)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        conn.TypeMap().RegisterType(dataType)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Note the above data type names for both types.

Give some mock data:

```
    history := []DayPriceModel{
        {time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -2), 4, 1, 2, 3},
        {time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1), 10, 5, 6, 7},
    }
```

an `insert` would be simply:

```
insertStmt := `INSERT INTO securities_price_history VALUES ($1, $2)`
_, err = conn.Exec(context.Background(), insertStmt, "something", history)
```

and the `update` something like this:

```
updateStmt := `UPDATE securities_price_history SET history = $1 WHERE symbol = $2`
_, err = conn.Exec(context.Background(), updateStmt, newHistory, "something")
```

**Test**

In order to have a complete, self-contained example of a test, we need a db and a small test program, taking into account the points mentioned above.

**DB**

A test DB using `psql` could be created like this:

```
create database equity;

\c equity

create type day_price_model as (
    date date,
    high float,
    low  float,               
    open float,
    close float
);

create table securities_price_history (
    symbol varchar,
    history day_price_model[]
);
```

**Go Program**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type DayPriceModel struct {
    Date  time.Time `json:"date"`
    High  float32   `json:"high"`
    Low   float32   `json:"low"`
    Open  float32   `json:"open"`
    Close float32   `json:"close"`
}

type SecuritiesPriceHistoryModel struct {
    Symbol  string          `json:"symbol"`
    History []DayPriceModel `json:"history"`
}

func RegisterDataTypes(ctx context.Context, conn *pgx.Conn) error {
    dataTypeNames := []string{
        "day_price_model",
        "day_price_model[]",
    }

    for _, typeName := range dataTypeNames {
        dataType, err := conn.LoadType(ctx, typeName)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        conn.TypeMap().RegisterType(dataType)
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=equity"
    conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer conn.Close(context.Background())

    err = RegisterDataTypes(context.Background(), conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    history := []DayPriceModel{
        {time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -2), 4, 1, 2, 3},
        {time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1), 10, 5, 6, 7},
    }

    insertStmt := `INSERT INTO securities_price_history VALUES ($1, $2)`
    _, err = conn.Exec(context.Background(), insertStmt, "something", history)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    sphm := &SecuritiesPriceHistoryModel{}
    selectStmt := `SELECT (symbol, history) FROM securities_price_history WHERE symbol=$1`
    err = conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), selectStmt, "something").Scan(sphm)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("after insert: %v\n", sphm)

    newHistory := append(history, DayPriceModel{time.Now(), 6, 3, 4, 5})

    updateStmt := `UPDATE securities_price_history SET history = $1 WHERE symbol = $2`
    _, err = conn.Exec(context.Background(), updateStmt, newHistory, "something")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), selectStmt, "something").Scan(sphm)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("after update: %v\n", sphm)
}
```

The output of the test program is:

```
after insert: &{something [{2023-03-10 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 4 1 2 3} {2023-03-11 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 10 5 6 7}]}
after update: &{something [{2023-03-10 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 4 1 2 3} {2023-03-11 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 10 5 6 7} {2023-03-12 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 6 3 4 5}]}
```

As you can see, a record has been inserted, the update has been performed successfully, because there are then three elements in the array and the data can be read from the DB.

If you then want to repeat the attempt, you should obviously remove the data from the table again, e.g. with `psql`. However, this should only be as small an example as possible to run an example with a local db.

Comment: So effectively, you have used `LoadType()` and `RegisterType()` right? I added that part to my code but still am getting this error for using UPDATE query: `failed to encode args[0]: unable to encode []models.DayPriceModel{models.DayPriceModel{Date:time.Date(2023, time.March, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), High:72.8, Low:69.4, Open:72.35, Close:69.7, LTP:70, PrevClose:72.75, }} into text format for unknown type (OID 16422): cannot find encode plan`. PS. Ignore the different model structure. I modified it while posting the question for ease of readability

Comment: Along with the UPDATE error, I am getting this for my INSERT statement: `can't scan into dest[0]: cannot scan unknown type (OID 16422) in binary format into *[]models.DayPriceModel`

Comment: And this for the Insert: `failed to encode args[1]: unable to encode []models.DayPriceModel{models.DayPriceModel{Date:time.Date(2023, time.March, 10, 19, 57, 56, 298261537, time.Local), High:4, Low:1, Open:2, Close:3, LTP:1, PrevClose:1,  DeliveryQuantity:1, DeliveryPercentage:1}, models.DayPriceModel{Date:time.Date(2023, time.March, 11, 19, 57, 56, 298262215, time.Local), High:10, Low:5, Open:6, Close:7, LTP:1, PrevClose:1, TotalTradedQuantity:1, TotalTradedValue:1, High52W:1, Low52W:1, TotalTrades:1}} into text format for unknown type (OID 16422): cannot find encode plan
exit status 1`

Comment: You can check my updated full code on [github](https://github.com/krush11/eodData). I have also pushed some additions provided by you, primarily RegisterDataType()

Comment: 1) How does your `PSQL_URL` env var look like? 2) What is the output of `select 'equity.day_price'::regtype::oid;` respective `select 'equity.day_price[]'::regtype::oid;`?

Comment: If you just use the full, self-contained example from my answer: does it work for you?

Comment: The format of my PSQL_URL env variable is `postgres://{username}:{my_password}@{my_db_url}/plutus`
Response is `16423` for the query `select 'equity.day_price'::regtype::oid;` and `16422` for `select 'equity.day_price[]'::regtype::oid;`

Comment: And yea all the 3 queries in your code runs properly when run separately so there must be some issue with my code. Will try to figure out the issue.

Comment: I had a quick look at your github project. In `RegisterDataTypes` a connection is acquired from the pool and then the registration happens on it and the connection is closed. Means: in any operation on the pool afterwards there are new Connections without the datatype registered, and hence the error. Change  `RegisterDataTypes` back and execute the following after `ParseConfig`: `config.BeforeAcquire = func(ctx context.Context, conn *pgx.Conn) bool {
  RegisterDataTypes(ctx, conn)
  return true
 }
`. This performs registration before acquiring a connection.